# Has one used XSLT BSF preprocessor in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Has anyone used BSF pre-processor in JMeter? What is the difference in the working between pre-processor and sampler? What is the difference between Beanshell processor and BSF processor?

My requirement is that I have a sample XML that I need to use to generate as many XMLs for the HTTP request I am going to load test. For this, I was planning to use BSF pre-processor to create an XML string using XSLT transformation of the template XML, within a loop (as many number of requests I want to generate). I would then use the string variable pointing to the created XML in each iteration of the loop for the corresponding HTTP request. So the questions in earlier paragraph are to validate this approach.

IF this approach is OK, I could not figure out how to use XSLT BSF pre-processor? I wrote as well as tried specifying the XSL in the script section, but could not figure out how to pass input XML? What does the String parameter input mean? It was throwing a NullPointerException for that parameter? IS that the way to specify input XML? If yes, please give an example.

Anybody who has worked in this, please share whatever inputs you can.

Thanks,
Paddy

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find answers below:

> What is the difference in the working between pre-processor and sampler

PreProcessor is executed **before** sampler. Pre- and PostProcessor execution time is not recorded so they're handy to use i.e. to prepare test data or do something with it after sampler end.

> What is the difference between Beanshell processor and BSF processor?

Beanshell test elements support only [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) language while BSF supports JavaScript, jexl, jacl, jml, etc.

For lightweight scripting it's better to use Beanshell as engine initialization time is less, however if your script is doing "heavy" operations it's better to use [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and Groovy as a language. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for scripting extension engines benchmark and details on how to install Groovy language support.

> how to pass input XML

It can be done via `Parameters` section which accepts any string.

If you have your XML file as JMeter variable you can access it from the script as:

```
String xml = vars.get("myVar");
```

**UPDATE: Example PreProcessor Code**

```
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;


TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("/path/to/your/xsl/file.xsl"));
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
Source xml = new StreamSource(new File("/path/to/your/source/xml/file.xml"));
transformer.transform(xml, new StreamResult(new File("/path/to/result/xml_or_html/file")));
```

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, thank you for explaining in detail about the differences. I am still not clear if pre-processor can create variables for subsequent steps or not. Also you have mentioned JSR223 Sampler and not pre-processor. Was it a typo or intended? Also I could not find Groovy listed as language in JSR223 sampler or pre-processor? Am I missing something? Also I am not quite understanding how to use BSF Xslt preprocessor, there is a script section/script file section (I used script file), and tried to pass input XML as parameter, but it threw null pointer in some setParameter method of bsf4j.

Comment: Hi Paddy. Pre-processor is able to create variables for the next steps (sampler or any other entity in current thread group), something like `vars.put("variable_name", "variable_value")` in the pre-processor followed by `${variable_name}` wherever you need to refer it. As for my JMeter 2.11 "groovy" language is available in the Language drop-down, however if it is not there just type `groovy` and it should be fine.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, thanks for the clarification. But one part where I really need help is the exception I am getting, I tried specifying the xsl both as inline and file separately (not together) and specified the string variable containing xml as input, isn't this correct, are you saying the script section should contain non-xslt code, can you show me an example, may be add it in your original reply itself? Thanks, Paddy

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri for the example, but I am wondering if we were to write the lines of code to do XSLT transform, why then they give "xslt" as a language option in the dropdown of types of pre-processors? Wouldn't it be to avoid those lines of code? Or are you suggesting to use another type of language like Java in conjunction with Beanshell pre-processor and this code snippet?

Comment: My solution is for Beanshell or JSR223 or BSF sampler with Java/Beanshell as a language. Apologies for misunderstanding your original question, didn't realize that it is for "xslt" language of BSF sampler. Perhaps this document can help: http://apachecon.com/us2007/downloads/ACUS-07-BSF-Rony-Flatscher-v20071020.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63004/discussion-between-paddy-and-dmitri-t).